# How would you approach this censored data problem? Time series or binary classification or other?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification, cross-validation

**The context**

I have a financial dataset containing variables used to predict if a person will accept loan offer or not, we use a binary variable to indicate that (0 for not accepted, 1 for accepted).

**The challenges**

1. before the person becomes a customer or not, there is a 6 months window in which the customer can think about it, so we record the date in which they accepted or rejected the offer as well as how long it took them to decide (how many weeks it took them)
2. Since we have given them a window to think about, there are lots of loans that don't have a decision yet, meaning that they are right censored since the 6 months window hasn't expired yet
3. Having censored data means there are lots of loans that we can't use as they haven't reached a decions, we will have to eliminate them from the final data set, if we decide to keep them we will have to leave the censored loans as value "0", but the model will interpret it as not completed, rather than censored.
4. Survival analysis is part of the options, but not preferred since we will have to go through a steep learning curve before we can implement it.

**Visual representation of the data**

```
id decision when(weeks) var1
a   0      3       aaa
b   1      2       bbb
c   0      1       ccc
d   1      4       aaa
e   0      2       aaa
... ... ... ...
f   1      3       bbb
g   1      2       ccc
h   0      5       ddd
i   0      6       ddd
k   0      9       bbb
```

**Possible solution**

1. Expand the dataset in a way that becomes a grouped time series problem, where you will have a time variable measured in weeks that will be increasing with time until it reaches the same value of "when(weeks) within each loan id. it will look like this:

```
id week  decision when(weeks)   var1 
a     0         0      3       aaa
a     1         0      3       aaa
a     2         0      3       aaa
a     3         0      3       aaa  (censored)
b     0         0      2       bbb
b     1         0      2       bbb
b     2         1      2       bbb  (accepted)
c     0         0      1       ccc
c     1         0      1       ccc  (rejected, looks like censored)
```

**The benefit**

I can fit a model and calculate the probabilities of acceptance per week (meaning that I will have an array will the values of week `0 to 26 (6 months)` and a probability attached to each of those. with this I can score each loan (including the censored ones) and predict, for example, what is the probability that a censored loan that is currently in week 3, will accept at week 4 or 5 or any number up to 26.

**The problem**

1. How do you do model selection/ cross validation for a grouped time series data like this, where also all the variables are static (fixed values), except one ("weeks") for each loan? You can't do a `train-test split` or `Walk Forward Validation` since we have multiple input variables and grouped data (multiple obeservations for the same loan id)
2. Is there a tool in `Scikit learn` or other that will help with cross validation given that there is such possibility for this scenario?

Comment: how did you solve this task in the end? Curious, since I am having somewhat similar issue with censored data for classification

Comment: I ended up working my way around it